# React Router component handling as a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to implement React-Router into an existing react app.

How can I use react-router to display components based on some conditions.

```
var displayRHS;

if(this.state.displayEventComponent){
        {/*
         * Events Menus
         */}
        displayRHS = <DisplayEventComponent
            parentFunc={this.displayComponentFunction}
            parentPropDay={this.state.day}
        />
    } else if (this.state.displayToDoListComponent){
        {/*
          * To Do List Menu
          */}
        displayRHS = <DisplayToDoListComponent
            parentCallback_2={this.updateDisplayToDoListComponent}
            updateList={this.state.updateDisplayToDoListComponent}
            displayIssuesNotList={false}
        />

    } else if (this.state.displayIssuesComponent) {
        {/*
          * Issues menu
          */}
        displayRHS = <DisplayIssuesComponent
            parentCallback_2={this.updateDisplayToDoListComponent}
            updateList={this.state.updateDisplayToDoListComponent}
            displayIssuesNotList={true}
        />

    }
```

Displaying Routes breaks

```
<Route exact path="/" component={displayRHS} />
```

How can I display these components with their respective props passed in as well?

Many Thanks in advance

PS, I am kind of thinking that a single page should be just that single page and using a routing library should be a sign that you should just have a page refresh instead..

Answer (score 0):

A single page application is called "single page" because the client fetches only one HTML page from the server side. A single page application can have multiple "client-side pages".

The application you are migrating used some condition because it didn't have a router. In react-router, the condition is matching a URL.

The react router allows you to navigate to a client-side page. You will use a component called `<Link>` to navigate to a client-side page. A virtual page is just a React component. Each available route needs to define a `Route`. You will need one Route for each client-side page:

```
<Router>
    <Route exact path="/" component={LayoutComponent}>
       <IndexRoute component={ToDoPage} />
       <Route path="/events" component={EventsPage} />
       <Route path="/issues" component={IssuesPage} />
    <Route/>
</Router>
```

The `LayoutComponent` will always be rendered:

```
class LayoutComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/events">Events</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/issues">Issues</Link></li>
            </ul>
           {this.props.children}
        );
    }
}
```

The value of `this.props.children` will be the page that matches the URL. So if the URL is `/issues` the component rendered in `{this.props.children}` will be the `IssuesPage` because we configured it that way:

```
<Route path="/issues" component={IssuesPage} />
```

Each of your pages can then render the components

ToDoPage:

```
class ToDoPage extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        this.state = {
            updateDisplayToDoListComponent: []
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <DisplayToDoListComponent
                parentCallback_2={this.updateDisplayToDoListComponent}
                updateList={this.state.updateDisplayToDoListComponent}
                displayIssuesNotList={false} />
        );
    }

    public updateDisplayToDoListComponent() {
        // do something
    }

}
```

EventsPage:

```
class EventsPage extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        this.state = {
            day: 1
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <DisplayEventComponent
                parentFunc={this.displayComponentFunction}
                parentPropDay={this.state.day} />
        );
    }

    public displayComponentFunction() {
        // do something
    }

}
```

IssuesPage:

```
class IssuesPage extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        this.state = {
            updateDisplayToDoListComponent: []
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <DisplayIssuesComponent
                parentCallback_2={this.updateDisplayToDoListComponent}
                updateList={this.state.updateDisplayToDoListComponent}
                displayIssuesNotList={true} />
        );
    }

    public updateDisplayToDoListComponent() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

This is not going to work out of the box and you are going to need to do some reading of the [react-router docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/v2.8.1/docs) but you should have enough details to figure out how to get it to work. You can also lear from ["Getting Started with React Router"](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-react-router).